AWS CDK Setup cognito + lambda - Forbidden
I'm attempting to set a simple "Hello Word" example where a user can access a lambda endpoint only after authenticating with Cognito via social login.
I have all the code which deploys succesfully and I can get through the login flow and get a valid cognito token, however when I invoke my endpoint I always get
{
    "message": "Forbidden"
}

So I've missed a step somewhere but not sure where.
cognito-cdk-stack.ts
export class CognitoCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
    public readonly userPool: cognito.UserPool;
    public readonly userPoolClient: cognito.UserPoolClient;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        // Create Cognito User Pool
        this.userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, 'UserPool', {
            userPoolName: 'my-app-user-pool',
            selfSignUpEnabled: true,
            signInAliases: { email: true },
            autoVerify: { email: true },
            standardAttributes: {
                givenName: { required: true, mutable: true },
                familyName: { required: true, mutable: true },
            },
            passwordPolicy: {
                minLength: 8,
                requireLowercase: true,
                requireUppercase: true,
                requireDigits: true,
                requireSymbols: true,
            },
        });

        const userPoolGoogleProvider = new cognito.UserPoolIdentityProviderGoogle(this, 'GoogleProvider', {
            userPool: this.userPool,
            clientId: '...',
            clientSecretValue: cdk.SecretValue.unsafePlainText('...'),
            scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
            attributeMapping: {
                email: cognito.ProviderAttribute.GOOGLE_EMAIL,
                givenName: cognito.ProviderAttribute.GOOGLE_GIVEN_NAME,
                familyName: cognito.ProviderAttribute.GOOGLE_FAMILY_NAME,
            },
        });

        this.userPool.registerIdentityProvider(userPoolGoogleProvider);

        this.userPoolClient = new cognito.UserPoolClient(this, 'UserPoolClient', {
            userPool: this.userPool,
            generateSecret: false,
            oAuth: {
                callbackUrls: ['http://localhost:3000/callback'],
                logoutUrls: ['http://localhost:3000'],
                flows: { implicitCodeGrant: true },
                scopes: [cognito.OAuthScope.OPENID, cognito.OAuthScope.EMAIL, cognito.OAuthScope.PROFILE],
            },
            supportedIdentityProviders: [cognito.UserPoolClientIdentityProvider.GOOGLE],
        });

        this.userPoolClient.node.addDependency(userPoolGoogleProvider)

        new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'UserPoolId', { value: this.userPool.userPoolId, exportName: 'UserPoolId' });
        new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'UserPoolClientId', { value: this.userPoolClient.userPoolClientId, exportName: 'UserPoolClientId' });
    }
}

lambda-cdk-stack.ts
export class LambdaCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const userPoolId = cdk.Fn.importValue('UserPoolId');

        const helloFunction = new PythonFunction(this, 'Hello', {
            functionName: 'hello',
            entry: 'lambda',
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_12,
            index: 'index.py',
            handler: 'handler',
            timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(900),
            memorySize: 2048,
        });

        // Create API Gateway
        const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'HelloApi', {
            restApiName: 'Hello World'
        });

        const importedUserPool = cognito.UserPool.fromUserPoolId(this, 'ImportedUserPool', userPoolId);

        const authorizer = new apigateway.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(this, 'CognitoAuthorizer', {
            cognitoUserPools: [importedUserPool],
        });

        // Create a protected resource
        const protectedResource = api.root.addResource('protected');
        protectedResource.addMethod('GET', new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(helloFunction), {
            authorizer: authorizer,
            authorizationType: apigateway.AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
        });

        // Add cors support
        api.root.addCorsPreflight({
            allowOrigins: ['*'],
            allowMethods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
            allowHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-Amz-Date', 'X-Api-Key', 'X-Amz-Security-Token', 'X-Amz-User-Agent'],
            allowCredentials: true,
        });

        // Output the API URL
        new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'ApiUrl', {value: api.url});
    }
}

To authenticate via Postman I call
https://<myPoolName>.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<myClientId>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&scope=openid+profile+email

And this returns me a code which looks like 17080341-c72b-4ad5-843c-8gb7bb740442 (example not real) then using the code I exchange it for a cognito token via
curl --location 'https://<myPoolDomain>.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=<...>' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<...>' \
--data-urlencode 'code=17080341-c72b-4ad5-843c-8gb7bb740442' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback'

And that works which gets me back
{
  "id_token": "ey...",
  "access_token": "ey...",
  "refresh_token": "ey...",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}

Finally I take the access_token and set that as Bearer token in the request to the lambda before getting Forbidden.
Where did I go wrong here?
